# Do $e^z+z$ and $ze^z +1$ have the same number of zeros in the strip -$\pi/2 < \text{Im}\,z< \pi/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

I am not sure where to go with the following problem:

Do the functions $f(z) = e^z+z$ and $g(z)= ze^z+1$ have the same number of zeros in the strip $-\pi/2 < \text{Im}\, z< \pi/2$?

I tried letting $\gamma $ be the curve that traces the rectangle with vertices $(R + i\pi/2), ( -R + i \pi/2), (-R - i\pi/2), (R - i \pi/2)$ with the positive orientation, $R>1$ and then I wanted to apply Rouche's theorem to show $|f(z)+g(z)| < |f(z)| +|g(z)|$ on $\gamma$ but I couldn't get the inequality to work out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to have a solution?

Comment: try and show that for all $\lambda \ge 0, f+\lambda g$ has no zeroes on the boundary where we take some $R$ large); that and the (easy) fact that $g$ has no zeroes there, imply the result (this is the most useful form of Rouche imho)

Comment: @mjw I should have written "zeros" not "solutions". I edited my post.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you!